# Set a standard transaction fee in bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, bitcoin.conf

Hello I was wondering if it is possible to set a standard transaction fee in bitcoind like 0.0001 BTC.
Because now it uses around 0.000026 BTC per transaction and it takes ages to confirm.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already got it I needed to use -mintxfee

Comment: `-paytxfee` is actually the standard way to set a fee/kb in your transactions.